# What does similar eigenvectors and eigenvalues of two matrices really mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-analysis, similarity

Empirically I've noticed that diagonally dominant matrix G and it's diagonal version D (diagonal elements of G on the diagonal and all other elements are set to zero) produce similar eigenvalues and eigenvectors. Under similar I mean that eigenvalues  $\lambda_G$ and $\lambda_D$ yield ( $\lambda_G$ - $\lambda_D$)~0.The same holds for eigenvectors (element-wise operation). My question is what this similarity actually means? Since eigenvectors and eigenvalues define direction and strength of the linear transformation performed by the matrix will this similarity mean that matrices G and D will have similar results when multiplied with some vector *p* ,i.e., will this similarity produce something like (G*p-D*p)~0.

Comment: Sounds to me like this is just Gershgorin: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem

Comment: From Gershgorin circle theorem I can only conclude that matrices G and D will have overlapping discs, i.e., eigenvalues of matrix D will be exactly the center of the discs produced by matrix G. .. If you could be a little bit more precise? Thx.

Comment: The eigen*vectors* generally have nothing to do with each other, since the eigenvectors of D are the elementary basis vectors, and the eigenvectors of G have not been constrained in any way. For the eigenvalues, the Gershgorin circle theorem seems like a pretty precise measure of similarity. Could you clarify what part of your question is not answered? What more are you hoping to prove/disprove/understand?

Comment: Thank you very much @AntonGeraschenko. I would just like to know if ( λG - λD)~0 implies  (Gp-Dp)~0. This is actually what I am dealing with....

Comment: I've voted to close since in its current form, the question does not seem sufficiently precise: the notation $\sim 0$ is not clear to me

Comment: ∼0 means "close to or approximately equal to zero"

Comment: "Close to zero" is still vague in this context -- after all, this is one reason for quantifying these things using epsilons and deltas and so on.

Comment: Let me try to clarify for myself. One is given a diagonally dominant n-by-n matrix G, with diagonal part D. One observes that there is a small number epsilon such that each eigenvalue of G is contained in the union of the discs with centres D_{11}, D_{22}, ..., D_{nn} and radius epsilon. [This is the closest interpretation I can find of your vague statement that lambda_G ~ lambda_D ] Are you now demanding that || Gp - Dp || \leq O(epsilon) for every unit-length vector p? Or merely demanding that || Gp-Dp || \leq O(epsilon) for every unit-length eigenvector of G? Or something else?